# Java Regular expression

Tags: java, html, regex

I have a string and a pattern that I want to search for in that string. Now, when I match the pattern in the string, I want to know the string that matches my pattern.

```
String template = "<P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"12\"> My Name is xyz </FONT></P>";

String pattern = "<FONT.*>";

Pattern.compile(pattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

How can I find out the string that matches the pattern in my template.

i.e I want to get `<FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"12\">` as the result. Is there any method provided by the regex library in Java which can help me?

### Update:

What is the regular expression that can match `<FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"12\"> My Name is xyz </FONT>` and `<LI><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"12\"> My Name is xyz </FONT></LI>` and it should not be greedy in a given text.

Comment: HTML?  Regular expressions?  `<FONT>`?  Where am I?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: possible duplicate of [java regular expression matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500992/java-regular-expression-matching)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the matched part of the string through [`matcher.group()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) .

A more elaborate way is to use [*capturing groups*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg). Put the part you want to "extract" from the matched string within parethesis, and then get hold of the matched part through, for instance `matcher.group(1)`.

In your particular example, you need to use a *reluctant qualifier* for the `*`. Otherwise, the `.*` will match all the way to the end of the string (since it ends with `P>`).

To illustrate both the use of [`Matcher.group()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) and [`Matcher.group(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29):

```
String template = "<P ALIGN=\"LEFT\"><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"12\"> My Name is xyz </FONT></P>";
String pattern = "<FONT (.*?)>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(template);

if (m.find()) {
    // prints: <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12"> My Name is xyz </FONT></P>
    System.out.println(m.group());

    // prints: FACE="Verdana" SIZE="12"
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful. I have another question. What pattern do i use to match a number in a given input?

Comment: For integers? You could use for instance "\\d+".

Comment: Thanks. What if there are multiple matches and i want to replace each one with some pattern??

Comment: You could use String.replaceAll... it actually takes a regexp as first argument. If you need the matched string, simply refer to it as $0.

Comment: i did not get what you are trying to convey. My question again

Lets say there were multiple matches and i want to replace each match with a different string, how can i do that?

Comment: How are the replacement-strings different from each other? can you give an example? If they are completely unrelated I suggest you do multiple calls to replaceFirst.

Comment: My template string is actually a combination of several of the tags that i have shown above. The size= attribute may have different values in each of these tags. Now, what i want to do is get the size to be used for the particular text from the <font> tag and replace the <Font>...</Font> with appropriate style tag like <p size="12pt;"> etc based on the size of the font.

Comment: import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
  public class PatternCompileTest1 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  String template="My Name is Sachin Tendulkar. Sachin is a good boy. Sachin is from India";
  String pattern = "Sachin";
  
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(template);
  
  int count = 1;
  while (m.find()) {
   String match = m.group();
   String replacement = match + count++;
   template = m.replaceFirst(replacement);
   System.out.println("template is " + template);
  }
 }
  }

Comment: This is a sample program that i have written but it goes into an infinite loop. I didn't know how to edit, so it looks a bit awkward...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a solution for you at the moment. (You could process the string and meanwhile construct a new string with the replaced strings.) You should start a new question. This is quite far from the original question.

Comment: I have found a solution.
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cat");
  Matcher m = p.matcher("one cat two cats in the yard");
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  while (m.find()) {
   m.appendReplacement(sb, "dog");
  }
  m.appendTail(sb);
  System.out.println(sb.toString());

Comment: Hi aioobe, I have one final question.


I want a regular expression that can match <FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"12\"> My Name is xyz </FONT> and

<LI><FONT FACE=\"Verdana\" SIZE=\"12\"> My Name is xyz </FONT></LI> and it should not be greedy

Comment: If you need clarifications to this answer, post comments here. If you have new question, then click "Ask Question".

Comment: I have created one.. But no responses
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495819/java-regular-expression-question

Comment: Note that you _must_ call m.find() before opening the groups (past hour of my life, good bye!)