# java regular expression matching

Tags: java, html, regex

What is the regular expression that can match the following 2 strings.

`Hi<Dog>Hi` and `<Dog>` in a given text.

### Update:

What regex will match this one?

```
<FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="16" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">If you access the web site click the link below:<FONT SIZE="12"></FONT></FONT>
```

`<FONT.*?<\/FONT>` matches only till the first `</FONT>`

Comment: There are *lots* of regular expressions which would match those strings. ".*" would do it for example... as well as matching everything else, too. Please give more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: `ab<XYZ>ab|<XYZ>` should match both of those ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `^([a-z]*)<[A-Z]*>\1$` will match these strings ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/5F22Z87whl)):

```
ab<XYZ>ab
<XYZ>
bleh<FOO>bleh
<>
```

It will not match these:

```
ab<XYZ>de
x<XYZ>y
FOO<foo>FOO
```

That is, the pattern is something like

> *`tag`*`<CONTENT>`*`tag`*

The same *`tag`* appears for both the "prefix" and the "suffix". Tag consists of zero or more lowercase letters. Content consists of zero or more uppercase letters. The prefix part is matched and [captured by group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1, and then a backreference `\1` is used to match that string again for the suffix.

The `[…]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Something like `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the lowercase vowels. `[^…]` is a *negated* character class. `[^aeiou]` matches one of *anything but* the lowercase vowels.

As a Java string literal, the pattern is `"^([a-z]*)<[A-Z]*>\\1$"`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you try to do, but this captures all the possibly relevant groups:

```
([a-z]+)?(<[A-Z]+>)([a-z]+)?
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Off the cuff I think it should be something like `(.*)<XYZ>\1`

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/ to check whether a regular expression matches a string

That's the only advice I can give you with the info you're giving us.